# Flutter & Dart file path not found

Tags: file, flutter, dart, path

I tried check file for exists but on all case flutter can't found file from directory.

**Code:**

```
  void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      final appDocDir = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    
      var path1 = '/assets/images/text.txt';
      var path2 = 'assets/images/text.txt';
      var path3 = '${appDocDir.path}/assets/images/banner.png';
    
      if (await File(path3).exists()) {
        print("File exists");
      } else {
        print("File don't exists");
      }
    }
```

**File** `pubspec.yaml`:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/icons/
```

Where I have error on my code?

Comment: did you put the names in pubspec.yaml as well ? `assets:
    - assets/images/text.txt`

Answer (score 0):

**Assets** directory should be in project root path.

- assets
- lib
- build
- etc.

**You should to write file names too:**
text.txt, banner.png

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/images/text.txt
    - assets/images/banner.png
    -
```

**path3:**

```
var path3 = '${appDocDir.path}/assets/images/banner.png';
```

You don't need to use path_provider to get image form assets dir.